# How to add backslash in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular, typescript

I have a div which return a status ,i want to add a backlash to a string returned eg Car1 \sold.

I am able to get status but I cant get a backlash here is what I have done.
In html:

```
<span>{{addBacklash(str)}}</span>
<div>{{store.status}}</div>
```

in Ts i have this function.

```
public stripslashes(str) {
    str = str.replace(/\\'/g, '\'');
    return str;
}
```

this does not work , what am I doing wrong here? or is there any simple method to achieve what I want? am newbie though

Comment: can you add this function `addBacklash` ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an inline template, then you need to escape \ as \ like in any other string.

```
<div>{{'\\'}}{{content}}</div>
```